# Can't add .aspx to iis7 mime types

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7, mime-types

I'm trying to add .aspx to my iis 7 Mine types.

I thought that checking asp.net in windows features would do the trick:
[image]

but no luck:
[image]

I have also tried "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" with no luck?  I'm I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MIME types missing in IIS 7 for ASP.NET - 404.17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319311/mime-types-missing-in-iis-7-for-asp-net-404-17)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I am able to execute .aspx files even though the extension doesn't appear in the Mine type list.  If I double click on the "Handler Mappings" icon then I can see .aspx in there... I guess that is where it needs to appear even though i'm not sure why.