# How to allow any file download in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iis

I am working on an application which downloads any type of file via HTTP. I've configured IIS in my local system for testing. I've added a virtual directory for file sharing. Earlier I was getting 500 internal server error for file downloads.

Then I added one MIMI type .*. But it is able to download files with extensions. I have some f**iles which have no extension not even a dot** after file name. For these files I am getting **404.17 not found error.**

Also when I request a file download, it tries to open instead of downloading. Examples include web pages (html, xml, aspx png etc). For these file types I found setting content type in http request (application/octet stream) will make the file to get downloaded. Also in IIS I've to set all files to correct MIMI type.

But for this I've to use POST request. But if I use POST, I am getting **405 method not allowed**.

I've tried all of the solutions but got no success.

Please help me where I am going wrong.

Also if you have any proper IIS configuration files or any links please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The standard for downloadable files is represented by the MIME type `application/octet-stream`.
So, you can just set the MIME type of your response to the following:

```
yourHttpResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

When any browser encounters such a MIME type, it downloads the file as a byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

No need to register MIME type.
You can create a proxy aspx web page(Download.aspx) for file download which will simply send the file to the client.

In that page's load event write following:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition",
"inline;filename=test.pdf");
Response.WriteFile(file);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/response-writefile

Comment: Thanks @NitinSawant. The problem with this is I'll get 405 method not allowed. Since I can't use GET requests to set request headers.

If I use POST, I'll egt 405 error.

Comment: Will it able to send ASPX also?

Comment: @Amit: Yes, On my server I am able to download ANY file. @ Kumar: can you post what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can allow this by using wildcard mime type mapping. See following links links for more detail;

http://forums.iis.net/t/1158023.aspx?How+can+I+configure+an+IIS+site+to+allow+any+file+type+to+be+downloaded+

[MIME types missing in IIS 7 for ASP.NET - 404.17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319311/mime-types-missing-in-iis-7-for-asp-net-404-17)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add specific mime type to download file. At the very first stage you need to hit url from browser from where you want to download the file. If it goes well then you should check with your code problem must be there.

If file don't get downloaded.Then you need to add a mime type to IIS. For that click on add fill file extension for example ".db" then fill mime type as "file/download" you will get that file downloaded.